# Magento 1.9.2.1 how to prevent core_config_data from getting malicious scripts

Tags: javascript, security, magento-1.9.2.1, compromise-injection

I have been scanning the website at Magento Scan and getting the following error:

> Magento Compromise Injection
>   Your site is compromised with injected JavaScript. (131)
>   The malicious code signature(s) has been found on the page.

In page source I can clearly see a malicious script included in header.

After further research I found that there are entries in **core_config_data** with path : '**design/head/includes**' and the value column has that malicious script.

I have not changed nor uploaded any extensions.

This has happened 3 to 4 times earlier and I am able to track how is this being injected.

When it happened for the first time and for every other times, I have changes database credentials but it didn't helped.

What measures should I take to prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the database credentials only will not help. You may need to change the following:

- Admin Panel URL path
- Admin Panel login credentials
- Check if there are any other admin users created
- Hosting Panel credentials
- FTP Login details (if any)
- SSH credentials

You also need to check whether there are any FTP, SSH users created without your knowledge.

Apart from above, if you are not using SSL (HTTPS) for your website, please ask your hosting provider to install it for you.

Please let me know if you are not sure how to check above details.

Comment: Alright will change all of the above and update you.

Comment: Also check for backdoors, eg webshells under /skin. See `mwscan` for a Magento malware scanner.

Comment: I have just installed Google's Invisible reCaptcha on the website for all forms and since then there are no such issues found. I wonder how can any script enter anything in database from magento's default forms.

Comment: @Willem I have found some backdoors and other malware codes in skin as well as in some of my code files for blog. I have removed all of them and changed the dir permissions to 755 and for files 644. Before the permissions were 777  for all.

Comment: @WasiqShahrukh, great work.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that almost all the configuration stores in the table: `core_config_data` In this case:

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data where path like '%design/head/includes%';
```

Comment: Sometimes malware is hidden in the `cms_blocks` and `cms_pages` tables. To be sure, you should scan your whole SQL dump.