# Magento 1.9.3.8: Magento Compromise Injection

Tags: magento-1.9

Your site is compromised with injected JavaScript. (71)
The malicious code signature(s) has been found on the page.

Please help.

Comment: How are you getting this error? can you share screenshots?

Comment: @ShoaibMunir here's the screenshot https://prnt.sc/mhfqrr

Comment: Where did you perform this test? You need to elaborate your question

Comment: I performed the test on Magento scanner https://account.magento.com/scanner

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following to make your website secure:

- Check in "View source" if you have any scripted loaded that you haven't added, remove if any
- Change database credentials
- Admin Panel URL path (Should not be /admin)
- Change Admin Panel login credentials
- Check if there are any other admin users created
- Change hosting Panel credentials
- Change FTP Login details (if any)
- Change SSH credentials
- Check if any other FTP and SSH user created that you didn't know
- Make your website secure SSL (HTTPS)

Reference:[Magento 1.9.2.1 how to prevent core_config_data from getting malicious scripts](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231984/magento-1-9-2-1-how-to-prevent-core-config-data-from-getting-malicious-scripts?rq=1)